# How to get first row and first column value of CSV in DataFactory?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

We are loading data from CSV to SQL table using data factory and CSV are stored in azure blob storage and if the loading fails I need to update the log the file loading  is failed with file Id.

File ID is present in first column of CSV .
How can I get that in Datafactory?

Comment: Could you tell us in which condition the copy active will fail?

Comment: suppose number of columns not matched with table,DataType might be differ

Comment: When we create the copy active, we must set the column mapping and data type mapping.  For all of this can avoid pipeline executing error. If you follow the right steps, it won't failed.

Answer (score -1):

Hi，Veeramalla Sandeep，I tried a lot ways but all failed.

Data Factory doesn't support do query or filter with the csv file.

That means that we can't not get the first row or column of the csv files.

Hope this helps.